# iPhone Dev - Trying to access every row of a sqlite3 table sequentially

Tags: iphone, objective-c, database, sqlite

this is my first time using SQL at all, so this might sound basic. I'm making an iPhone app that creates and uses a sqlite3 database (I'm using the libsqlite3.dylib database as well as importing "sqlite3.h"). I've been able to correctly created the database and a table in it, but now I need to know the best way to get stuff back from it.

How would I go about retrieving all the information in the table? It's very important that I be able to access each row in the order that it is in the table. What I want to do (if this helps) is get all the info from the various fields in a single row, put all that into one object, and then store the object in an array, and then do the same for the next row, and the next, etc. At the end, I should have an array with the same number of elements as I have rows in my sql table. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My SQL is rusty, but I think you can use `SELECT * FROM myTable` and then iterate through the results. You can also use a `LIMIT`/`OFFSET`(1) structure if you do not want to retrieve all elements at one from your table (for example due to memory concerns).

(1) Note that this can perform unexpectedly bad, depending on your use case. Look [here](http://www.sqlite.org/cvstrac/wiki?p=ScrollingCursor) for more info...

Answer (score 2):

> How would I go about retrieving all the information in the table? It's
>   very important that I be able to access each row in the order that it
>   is in the table.

That is not how SQL works. Rows are not kept in the table in a specific order as far as SQL is concerned. The order of rows returned by a query is determined by the ORDER BY clause in the query, e.g. ORDER BY DateCreated, or ORDER BY Price.

But SQLite has a rowid virtual column that can be used for this purpose.  It reflects the sequence in which the rows were inserted. Except that it might change with a VACUUM. If you make it an INTEGER PRIMARY KEY it should stay constant.

```
          order by rowid
```